# How to configure a package in CentOS?

Tags: centos, software-installation

I tried to configure a package with:

```
OdaOda:~/src/ngx_openresty-1.7.10.2$ ./configure --with-luajit
```

After that, I get an error:

```
platform: linux (linux)
No gmake nor make found in PATH.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing `make`?

Comment: Wrong question, this has nothing to do with either centos, nor centos packages, nor centos packages configuration, but in short - `yum groupinstall "Development tools"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the *Development Tools* set of packages in order to have the `make` program (and others) available. To install them, open the terminal and type the following command as root:

```
yum group install "Development Tools"
```

Or

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```